# ComponentDidUpdate state keeps changing

Tags: reactjs

I have a tagOptions state that continuous is updated even with my condition I am still getting the component to render too many times and this overrides my state. Can anyone give me even a dirty firx so that this is only updated once.

```
state = { 
    tagOptions:[],
    value:[],
    init: false
  };

componentDidUpdate() {
    /* Gets hits from Algolia and ensures tagOptions is not overwritten by props.hits */
    if(!this.state.init) 
    {
      console.log(this.state.init)
      if(this.props.hits.length) {
        this.setState({ 
          ...this.state,
          init: true,
          tagOptions:this.transformHits(this.props.hits)
        }) 
      } 
    }  
    console.log("Update2",this.state.tagOptions) 
  }
```

Comment: what is the console.log of  this.props.hits.length

Comment: To fetch initial data once `componentDidMount` is the right place to do that.

Comment: are you reseting `init` state to `false` anywhere in the component?

Comment: componentDidMount will not get my original props.hits from my database in time so that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Init is only used inside this componentDidUpdate not used anywhere else in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the callback form of `setState` and see if that changes anything:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (!this.state.init && this.props.hits.length) {
    this.setState(() => ({
      init: true,
      tagOptions: this.transformHits(this.props.hits),
    }));
  }
}
```

Perhaps if any other functions are updating `init`, this *could* prevent it from being overwritten.

Also you don't need do `...this.state` in `setState`, React should handle that for you.

Comment: So I added a callback and logged my state.tagOptions. And I noticed the callback is only called when I refresh the page but during anytime testing my code.

Comment: By the way, it's also not a good idea to update state in `componentDidUpdate`--is there any reason not ti set `tagOptions` whenever you set `init`?

Answer (score 0):

[componentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#componentdidupdate) is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

So if you have to change the tagOptions state, once you get data from props.hits then you can add a check, if the previous props are not equal to current props

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.hits.length && (this.props.hits !== prevProps.hits) ) {
    this.setState({
      tagOptions: this.transformHits(this.props.hits),
    });
  }
}
```

You don't need to change init state anymore